# "enthusiast" vs "aficionado" vs "fan"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, difference

> Tennis and Cricket **enthusiast**.
>
> Formula-1 and MotoGP **fan**.

I have included these two lines in my (high school format) résumé. I want to depict the idea that I know most of the rules of Tennis and Cricket. On the other hand, I love watching Formula-1 and MotoGP races, but do not know all the rules of the game. I do not want the interviewer to get the wrong idea that I know everything about all the mentioned things.

I searched the meanings of the words and these were the results:

- **enthusiast** - a person who is very interested in a particular activity or subject.  [Source](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01ZFLLJjIQQX-sUJPQc6Aqcqu30lw%3A1602667025050&source=hp&ei=EcKGX985-pzj4Q_Z35XwBQ&q=enthusiast&oq=enth&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgcIIxDJAxAnMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCxAxAUEIcCMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABAUEIcCMgUIABCxAzICCAAyAggAMgUIABCxAzIFCAAQsQM6BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6CAgAELEDEIMBOg4ILhCxAxCDARDHARCjAjoNCAAQsQMQgwEQFBCHAjoFCC4QsQNQ1AlY4hhgnR5oAHAAeACAAeYLiAGcFpIBCTAuMi43LTEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab)
- **aficionado** - a person who is very knowledgeable and enthusiastic about an activity, subject, or pastime. [Source](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03fqig8tl6hW2rDF7ycHVNLuU-s0g:1602667029509&q=define%20aficionado&forcedict=aficionado&dictcorpus=en&expnd=1)
- **fan** - a person who has a strong interest in or admiration for a particular person or thing. [Source](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03QnBw6hl1jPi2fuH1fcMN-Z_LnGA:1602667067574&q=define%20fan&forcedict=fan&dictcorpus=en&expnd=1)

What prevented me from using the word ***aficionado*** is that it means someone who is knowledgeable. I won't consider myself on that level yet. Hence my question, are the two statements above idiomatically correct? Or should I consider opting for other alternatives? Also please do mention those alternatives.

Comment: In English, they all mean more or less the same, but enthusiast is formal, aficionado is mainly American, and not always widely understood even there, and fan is informal.

Answer (score 1):

In English, they all mean more or less the same. In my experience, enthusiast is formal, aficionado is mainly American, and not always widely understood even there, and fan is informal.

> a person who is very interested in and involved with a particular
> subject or activity
> [Enthusiast (Cambridge Dictionaries)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enthusiast)
>
> Someone who is very interested in and enthusiastic about a particular
> subject
> [Aficionado (Cambridge Dictionaries)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aficionado)
>
> a person who is very much interested in and spends a lot of time
> watching or reading about esp. an entertainer or sports team
> [Fan (Cambridge Dictionaries)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fan)

Answer (score 0):

*Enthusiast*, *aficionado*, and *fan*  are all the words used to describe someone who has a strong interest in or passion for something.

"Enthusiast" is a broad term that can be used to describe someone who has a keen interest or enthusiasm for a particular activity, hobby, or subject. For example, a music enthusiast may enjoy listening to and learning about various genres of music.

"Aficionado" is a more specific term that refers to someone who has a deep knowledge and appreciation for a particular activity, hobby, or subject. For example, a wine aficionado may have extensive knowledge about different types of wine, including their origins, flavors, and pairings.

"Fan" is a more casual term that is often used to describe someone who has a strong liking or support for a particular sports team, musician, or celebrity. For example, a football fan may enjoy watching games and rooting for their favorite team.

Summing up:  While all these terms describe someone who has a strong interest in something, "enthusiast" is the most general term, "aficionado" is more specific and denotes expertise and deep knowledge, and "fan" is the most casual and often associated with entertainment.